# Why is the SQL produced by LINQ-to-Entities so inefficient?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

The following (cut down) code excerpt is a Linq-To-Entities query that results in SQL (via ToTraceString) that is *much* slower than a hand crafted query. Am I doing anything stupid, or is Linq-to-Entities just bad at optimizing queries?

I have a ToList() at the end of the query as I need to execute it before using it to build an XML data structure (which was a whole other pain).

```
var result = (from mainEntity in entities.Main
              where (mainEntity.Date >= today) && (mainEntity.Date <= tomorrow) && (!mainEntity.IsEnabled)
              select new
              {
                  Id = mainEntity.Id,
                  Sub =
                      from subEntity in mainEntity.Sub
                      select
                      {
                          Id = subEntity.Id,
                          FirstResults =
                              from firstResultEntity in subEntity.FirstResult
                              select new
                              {
                                  Value = firstResultEntity.Value,
                              },
                          SecondResults =
                              from secondResultEntity in subEntity.SecondResult
                              select
                              {
                                  Value = secondResultEntity.Value,
                              },
                          SubSub =
                              from subSubEntity in entities.SubSub
                              where (subEntity.Id == subSubEntity.MainId) && (subEntity.Id == subSubEntity.SubId)
                              select
                                  new
                                  {
                                      Name = (from name in entities.Name
                                              where subSubEntity.NameId == name.Id
                                              select name.Name).FirstOrDefault()
                                  }
                          }
              }).ToList();
```

While working on this, I've also has some real problems with Dates. When I just tried to include returned dates in my data structure, I got internal error "1005".

Answer (score 7):

Just as a general observation and not based on any practical experience with Linq-To-Entities (yet): having four nested subqueries inside a single query doesn't look like it's awfully efficient and speedy to begin with.

I think your very broad statement about the (lack of) quality of the SQL generated by Linq-to-Entities is not warranted - and you don't really back it up by much evidence, either.

Several well respected folks including [Rico Mariani](http://blogs.msdn.com/ricom/archive/2007/06/22/dlinq-linq-to-sql-performance-part-1.aspx) (MS Performance guru) and [Julie Lerman](http://www.thedatafarm.com/blog/2009/03/31/UsingPreCompiledLINQToEntitiesQueriesInWebAppsAndServices.aspx) (author of "Programming EF") have been showing in various tests that in general and overall, the Linq-to-SQL and Linq-to-Entities "engines" aren't really all that bad - they achieve overall at least 80-95% of the possible peak performance. Not every .NET app dev can achieve this :-)

Is there any way for you to rewrite that query or change the way you retrieve the bits and pieces that make up its contents?

Marc

Comment: Aren't nested sub-queries *recommended* in LINQ-to-Entities (e.g. instead of joins)? See http://blogs.msdn.com/esql/archive/2007/11/01/EntitySQL_5F00_Tip_5F00_1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not materializing the result immediately by calling .ToList()?  I'm not sure it will make a difference, but you might see improved performance if you iterate over the result instead of calling .ToList() ...

```
foreach( var r in result )
{
  // build your XML
}
```

Also, you could try breaking up the one huge query into separate queries and then iterating over the results. Sending everything in one big gulp might be the issue.